# android studio workmanager pending status

Tags: android, android-studio, android-workmanager

what does PENDING status mean for a workmanager?
Because I couldn't find anything on the internet....
this is how I checked the status

```
Log.d("tag", WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfosForUniqueWork(getString(R.string.work_name)).toString())
```

Comment: `getWorkInfosForUniqueWork` returns a `ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>>` as it is an asynchronous operation. Where are you using [AndroidX Coroutines'](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent) [`CallbackToFutureAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/concurrent/futures/CallbackToFutureAdapter) or [`await()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/concurrent/futures/package-summary#await) to transform it into an actual `List<WorkInfo>`?

Comment: I didn't understand the question.... but I only need to log the status of the workmanager for debug reasons, so I called .toString() on it